# What is screen Scale value for Lumia 950 and 950 XL?

Tags: winrt-xaml, scale, screen-size, windows-10-mobile, lumia

Since I don't have any of the mentioned phones with Windows 10 Mobile, can someone, who have **Lumia 950** or **950 XL** , run the following few lines of code in blank UWP application project to get the `Scale` value out of this device (to figure out [effective resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx) eventually):

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ### snipped start ###

        var qualifiers = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues;
        string scale;

        if (qualifiers.TryGetValue("Scale", out scale))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(scale);
        }

        // ### snipped end ###
    }
}
```

Please post the integer number from the output window as an answer - will be much appreciative!

PS. Suspecting that it should be **400** for 950 and **450** for 950 XL, but would like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in case anybody will look for it later - the scale is **400** for Lumia **950**, thanks to colleague, who bought it recently.